# How to return javascript in mvc when I click the button to jump from one page to another and cookie overtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

When user log in my web,I set the cookie's  timeout  to be 30 min,after timeout,when user want to go to page B from page A,I will check the cookie time out and return the javascript to the brower,what's wrong with my codes?It seems that I return the content because all the codes below will display in the browser but not execute(and I have to refresh the url and is OK).

**Method 1:not work**

```
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
      var url = string.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}",
                FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl,
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
      if (SessionHelper.Get("UserName") == null)
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(
       "<script>alert('Login overtime!Loggin again please!');
       window.location.href='"+url +"';</script>");
   }
```

**Method 2:not work**

```
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
      var url = string.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}",
                FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl,
                filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
      if (SessionHelper.Get("UserName") == null)
       filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
        {
         ContentType = "text/html",
         Content = "<script>alert('Login overtime!Loggin again please!');
        window.location.href='" + url + "';<script>"
        };
     }
```

Comment: Why dont you just use RedirectResult instead of ContentResult? You could pass over the reason as a tempdata.

Comment: Thanks,Before redirect the url,I want the alert the overtime message.How could I alert the tempdata in OnAuthorization function?Every page I have to verify,I can not pass tempdata in all page or all controller.

Comment: I'll post a quick answer for you 2 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (SessionHelper.Get("UserName") == null)
        {

            filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("RedirectReason", "Login overtime!Loggin again please!");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");

        }
    }
```

Then add this to your view...

`@TempData["RedirectReason"]`

and the error will be displayed on your login form.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

we should not return javascript alerts..instead see what the error code you are getting when you make a service call after the cookie timesout. based on that, add the below  to your master page

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            statusCode: {
                407: function () {
                  //your redirection code here
                 window.location.reload();
                }
            },


        });

//do not use 407 in your code..see what code u get,then replace 407 with ur status code
```